# How to filter ng-repeat list on empty string values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

How can I filter an ng-repeat to show all items where a certain columnfield is an empty string? When I try this it always seem to give the full list. I only want to see the person with id 1.

[Fiddlejs example](http://jsfiddle.net/u7g73caq/)

Controller:

```
var people = [{
                name: '',
                age: 32,
                id: 1
            }, {
                name: 'Jonny',
                age: 34,
                id: 2
            }, {
                name: 'Blake',
                age: 28,
                id: 3
            }, {
                name: 'David',
                age: 35,
                id: 4
            }];

 $scope.filteredPeople = $filter('filter')(people, {
     name: ''
 });

 $scope.people = people.slice(0);
```

View:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople">
     <h4>{{p.name}} ({{p.age}}) id: {{p.id}}</h4>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular's `'filter'` in `'ng-repeat'`:

```
// In template:
<li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople | filter : filterPeople">
     <h4>{{p.name}} ({{p.age}}) id: {{p.id}}</h4>
</li>

// In controller:
$scope.filterPeople = function(item) {
    return !item.name;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To list users that have name:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople" ng-if="p.name !== ''">
     <h4>{{p.name}} ({{p.age}}) id: {{p.id}}</h4>
</li>
```

To list only users that do not have name:

```
<li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople" ng-if="p.name === ''">
     <h4>{{p.name}} ({{p.age}}) id: {{p.id}}</h4>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass third parameter to filter saying `true` which will perform strict check

```
$scope.filteredPeople = $filter('filter')(people, {
    name: ''
}, true);
```

[**Forked JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bex593r3/)

Comment: @Jim Peeters does it helped??